# getchar() != EOF K&R

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm very sorry for asking this silly question and also, I've checked in the threads related to this post still found no help. In the code snippet below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int c;
  while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c); 
}
```

Q1: If I input `hello`, the output is `hello`. Shouldn't it just be `h` because although getchar can read entire string but it'll accept only one character and thus produce the output as `h`?

Q2: Assume I input `n`, shouldn't it proceed as below:

1. getchar function will store 'n' as a single character.
2. Since the data type of c is an integer, the ASCII value of n is stored ie 110.
3. This is tested against the EOF's integer value or -1 and since the result is true or Boolean has a value of 1, the body of the loop is executed.
4. After execution of the contents in the body of loop, the control again goes back to the condition in 'while' loop and the user is prompted again to enter the character and this cycle goes on until it isn't equal to EOF ?

Comment: you're just copying the chars you get in input as input. But c always holds the last char that you typed, forgetting the others.

Comment: Doesn't Q2 answer your question in Q1? When you type `hello`, it reads `h` the first time, and after execution of the body it goes back to the beginning of the loop. The next time it reads `e`, and so on.

Comment: Upvoted for using `int c;` ....but the `main` signature is wrong. `int main(void)`.

Comment: The cycle goes on until the input **is** equal to EOF.

Answer (score 5):

`getchar()` only consumes one character from the input stream. All of the other characters remain in the input stream for subsequent examination.

The first time you call `getchar()`, it returns `'h'`. The second time, it returns `'e'`, then `'l'`, and so on. The sixth time it is invoked, it returns the end-of-line indicator `'\n'`. The seventh time it is invoked, it pauses, waiting for the user to type more data.

Only when the user indicates end of file will the function return EOF. If the input is from a terminal, the user might indicate end of file by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Unix, Linux) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (DOS, Windows). If the input is from a disk file, end of file is indicated after all of the file's content is exhausted.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess, I might want to read the entire functionality of getchar. Anyhow, I'm obliged to you all !